# Change data on navbar when logout and login with another account

Tags: reactjs, axios

**Aim :**
I want to put `firstName` and `lastName` on my Navbar. So, I'm using axios request by id with `userId`

**EDIT:** Thanks to @Isaac, I have no more infinite loop when I'm using componentWillUpdate() now.

**Problem :** Data doesn't change (`firstName` and `lastName`) when I'm logout and login with another account

No problems from servers.

here a picture : [image]
Description : I've login as `a` & `g` (`firstName` and `lastName`), then I've logout and login as `j` & `j`.

`navbar.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { fade } from '@material-ui/core/styles/colorManipulator';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import AuthA from '../store/actions/AuthA';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../Navbar.css';
import NavbarV from './NavbarV';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import axios from 'axios';

class NavbarC extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
     this.state = {
       client:[]
    }
  }


  componentWillMount(){
    this.getUser();
  }

  getUser(){
 axios.get (`http://localhost:3002/api/clients/${localStorage.getItem("userId")}?access_token=${localStorage.getItem("token")}`)
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({client: res.data}, () => {
        console.log(this.state)
      })
    })
  }

shouldComponentUpdate(nextState){
  return (this.state.client.firstName !== nextState.firstName || 
this.state.client.lastName !== nextState.lastName);
}

  componentWillUpdate(){
    this.getUser();
    console.log(this.state)
  }

  logout = () => {
    this.props.authfn.logout();
  };

    render() {

        return(
            <NavbarV logout = {this.logout}
           firstName={this.state.client.firstName}
           lastName={this.state.client.lastName}
           userId={this.props.userId}
            auth = {this.props.auth}
            classes={this.props.classes}/>
        )
    }
}

NavbarC.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  firstName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  lastName: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    auth: state.AuthR.auth,
    firstName: state.AuthR.firstName,
    lastName: state.AuthR.lastName,
    userId: state.AuthR.userId
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    authfn: AuthA(dispatch)
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (withStyles(styles)(withRouter(NavbarC)));
```

If someone have a solution or any questions, I'm here :)
thank you all in advance

Comment: You should use componentDidMount instead

Comment: @vitomadio: No. `componentWillMount` will only be triggered once. And `componentWillMount` is expecting to behave exactly same as `componentDidMount`, except `componentWillMount` comes first

Comment: Yes you're right, my bad, thas why I edited the comment

Comment: Why do you need componentWillUpdate()? It's kinda useless

Comment: `this.state.client.firstName !== nextState.firstName` doesn't the next state have the `client` object?

Comment: You should not call `this.setState()` in componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. It will cause infiniti-loop

Comment: @AlvinTheodora because if I am logout and login with another account, it won't change ;)

Comment: @aseferov How can I avoid setState ?

Comment: @TROGER Anthony remove `this.getUser();` from ` componentWillUpdate `

Comment: @aseferov, okay thanks, I've tried. The problem, it doesn't change `firstName` and `lastName` on the navbar when I'm logout and login with another account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it !

This is a solution :

```
 componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({ 
      userId: localStorage.getItem("userId"),
      token: localStorage.getItem("token")
    }, () => {
      this.getUser();
    })
  }

  getUser = () => {
 axios.get (`http://localhost:3002/api/clients/${this.state.userId}?access_token=${this.state.token}`)
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({ client: res.data, userId: localStorage.getItem("userId") }, () => {
        console.log(this.state)
      })
    })
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if(prevState.userId !== this.props.userId) {
      this.setState({ userId: this.props.userId }, () => {
        this.getUser();
      })
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should avoid `componentWillUpdate` lifecycle as it's been deprecated.

And for your case, `this.getUser();` will be triggered to pull data which then trigger `this.setState({client: res.data})`. When the app executing `this.setState()`, your component will be re-render so there's no need to have any other componentLifeCycle.

```
class NavbarC extends Component {

  state = { client:[], userID: null, token: null };


  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({ 
      userID: localStorage.getItem("userId"),
      token: localStorage.getItem("token")
    }, () => {
      this.getUser();
    })
  }

  getUser(){
 axios.get (`http://localhost:3002/api/clients/${this.state.userID}?access_token=${this.state.token}`)
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({ client: res.data }, () => {
        console.log(this.state)
      })
    })
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if(prevState.userID !== this.state.userID) {
      this.getUser();
    }
  }

  logout = () => this.props.authfn.logout();

  render() {

    return(
      <NavbarV 
        logout = {this.logout}
        firstName={this.state.client.firstName}
        lastName={this.state.client.lastName}
        userId={this.props.userId}
        auth = {this.props.auth}
        classes={this.props.classes} />
    )}
}
```

Comment: How can I avoid this.setState?

Comment: Why should you? `this.setState` is a perfect way to re-render your component after fetching data from endpoint

Comment: @TROGERAnthony: Try again with my answer. The idea is to store userID into state, and implement `componentDidUpdate` and compare state to decide if to fire network request

Comment: Hello @Isaac, I've tried your answer. I understand your idea :) however, I still have an infinite loop and it doesn't change `firstName` and `lastName` when I change of account (logout and login with another account)

Comment: I've just made some slight changes to `componentDidMount` method. Please try again

Comment: Yep, it's better, the infinite loop disappears. Now It still doesn't change `firstName` and `lastName` ^^'

Comment: Can you share the output of `console.log(this.state)` @ `getUser `?

Comment: Sure, I've edit you my post ;) I've login as `a` & `g` (as `firstName` and `lastName`) then logout and login as `j` & `j`